# Can't clear ListBox while item is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Hello today I was experimenting with WPF and I found that when a ListBox has a selected item it will not allow it to be modified and hang the app

```
        private void Button_Click_7(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptBox.Items.Clear();
        Functions.PopulateListBox(ScriptBox, "./Scripts", "*.txt");
        Functions.PopulateListBox(ScriptBox, "./Scripts", "*.lua");
    }
```

I'm new to WPF so it would help a lot to find out why this happens.

Edit:Might Be Mscorelib.dll (Its Not)

***Edit: A Try Catch Worked WITH Peregrine's Improvements***

Comment: Please remember to read tag descriptions before you use them, so as to not misuse them. Your question isn't about the Visual Studio application, so the `[visual-studio]` tag isn't relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you're not going to go the full MVVM route, it's still a good idea to separate your application's data from the UI controls.

1] In the constructor of your Window, create an `ObservableCollection<string>` and set this as the `ItemsSource` of the `ScriptBox` control.

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _scriptBoxCollection;

public MyView()
{
    _scriptBoxCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    ScriptBox.ItemsSource = _scriptBoxCollection ;
}
```

2] Change your `PopulateListBox()` method to just return a collection of file names. Following the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle), such methods shouldn't care how the data they generate is used.

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<string> GetMatchingFiles(string folder, string fileSpec) { ... }
```

The return value is `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` in line with the [Microsoft guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections).

3] Change the button click handler so that it updates the observable collection.

```
private void Button_Click_7(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _scriptBoxCollectionClear();

    foreach(var item in Functions.GetMatchingFiles("./Scripts", "*.txt")
        _scriptBoxCollection.Add(item);

    Functions.GetMatchingFiles("./Scripts", "*.lua")
        _scriptBoxCollection.Add(item);
}
```

The `ForEach` construct is required as the standard `ObservableCollection` doesn't support `AddRange()`.

---

Add this to Functions.cs (and depricate PopulateListBox() and any other similar methods that are writing data directly to UI controls)

```
public static ReadOnlyCollection<string> GetMatchingFiles(string folder, string fileType) 
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    var dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(folder); 
    var files = dinfo.GetFiles(fileType); 
    foreach (var file in files) 
    { 
        result.Add(file.Name); 
    } 
    
    return result.AsReadOnly();
}
```

Comment: Thx So Much Just Im Not That Good At Wpf To Implenent That But It Helped Me

Comment: Wait It Might Be A Problem With MScorlib.dll

Comment: Im Yrying This Thogh

Comment: Oof 
In Funtions.cs

public static void PopulateListBox(System.Windows.Controls.ListBox lsb, string Folder, string FileType)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(Folder);
            FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles(FileType);
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                lsb.Items.Add(file.Name);
            }
        }

Will Not Allow Me To Use This Probably How This Was Coded

Comment: @Pak That looks like 20 year old winforms code, rather than modern WPF. I've added sample code above showing how I would generate and use the list of matching files.

Comment: Wait The Name item Doesnt exist in current context

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `ScriptBox.UnselectAll()` or `ScriptBox.SelectedIndex = -1` ?

Assuming ScriptBox is your Listbox.